# Drive YUI Compressor with PowerShell and Write Syntax Errors to .txt file as a Visual Studios Pre Build Script

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, powershell, yui, syntax-error

ok so in a nut shell, I've got PowerShell driving YUI Compressor to do some JS compression as part of a visual studios pre-build event. though syntax errors are likely to be very infrequent, I'd like to know about those errors if they do occur and with the script I have running now, I have not been able to have Visual Studios display the errors in the build log or to have the powershell script write any errors YUI gives to a .txt file to be viewed later. (the latter would be the preferred)

> Write-Host "Working in $args"
>
> attrib -R $args*.* /s
>
> Get-ChildItem $args -include *.js -recurse -force | %{java -jar C:\Tools\yuicompressor-2.4.6\build\yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar ($*.fullname) -o ($*.fullname) --type js --nomunge}

Write-Host in the PowerShell script allows me to then create a .txt with the output using the following cmd in Visual Studios:

> powershell.exe -file "$(ProjectDir)....\PowerScripts\Pre_Build_Public.ps1">> “C:\Tools\Pre_Build_Report.txt” "$(ProjectDir)Scripts"

would this work with any errors given from YUI as well?

If more clarification is needed, please let me know. I want to make this as easy as possible and thanks for taking the time to look this over.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the stderr stream using the `2>&1` operator:

```
 powershell.exe -file "$(ProjectDir)....\PowerScripts\Pre_Build_Public.ps1" 2>&1 >> "C:\Tools\Pre_Build_Report.txt" "$(ProjectDir)Scripts"
```

I believe, however, that PowerShell's internal error handling doesn't write to stderr.  You'll need to do that by hand.  At the end of your `Pre_Build_Public.ps1` script, I'd do something like:

```
 foreach( $err in $error )
 {
      Write-Output $err
 }
```

This will send each error to stdout.

It looks like PowerShell v3 will support redirecting PowerShell's internal error stream.